# Minimum Spring-batch and spring-context version compatible with Java 11?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, upgrade, java-11

I need to upgrade my `maven` project to `Java 11`, so I am wondering:

1. What is the min version of `Spring Framework` and `spring-batch version` supported in Java 11?
2. What to be change in the pom?

As of now I know:

1. My project is not a spring-boot.
2. I know the `Spring version` should be at least `5.1`.
3. ```
   <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.8.1</version>-->
   <configuration>
        <release>11</release>-->
        <encoding>iso-8859-1</encoding>
   </configuration>
   ```

The pom contains the following:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>jo.tatova.honki</groupId>
<artifactId>toko</artifactId>
<version>1.0.40-SNAPSHOT</version>

<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>toko</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>jo.tatova.parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-pom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

    <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.springframework.batch>2.1.9.RELEASE</org.springframework.batch>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.2</org.slf4j-version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.batch}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jo.tatova</groupId>
        <artifactId>record-utils</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jo.tatova.honki</groupId>
        <artifactId>honki-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.110-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.informix</groupId>
        <artifactId>informix-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <encoding>iso-8859-1</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                <shadedClassifierName>jar-with-dependencies</shadedClassifierName>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/LICENSE*</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/license.txt</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/NOTICE*</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/notice.txt</exclude>
                            <exclude>LICENSE</exclude>
                            <exclude>license.txt</exclude>
                            <exclude>NOTICE</exclude>
                            <exclude>overview.html</exclude>
                            <exclude>readme.txt</exclude>
                            <exclude>testpool.jocl</exclude>
                            <exclude>XPP3_1.1.4c_MIN_VERSION</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Main-Class>jo.tatova.honki.toko.TokoParser</Main-Class>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: "*What is the min version of Spring Framework*" "*I know the Spring version should be at least 5.1"* You answered your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know the Spring version should be at least 5.1

> <org.springframework.batch>2.1.9.RELEASE</org.springframework.batch>

You seem to be upgrading Spring Batch from v2. Since your Spring version should be at least v5.1, you need to upgrade Spring Batch to v4 (which is based on Spring Framework v5) and requires Java 8 at a minimum. So the answer to your question about the minimum Java version is Java 8, but you should be able to use Java 11 if you want.

Comment: What you see in the pom is existing legacy code which I should upgrade it to java 11.
The question is what should be changed in the pom?

Comment: Yes I understood that, that's why I concluded that you are upgrading from v2. You need to upgrade Java version to 11, spring framework version to 5.1, batch version to 4.3, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I have just changed version to 11, it compiled and also runs. It works without any error, and it is a little strange for me why it does not complain against spring version and batch version which I did not upgrade to 5.1 and 4.3.
Do you have any idea? Or do you think it will cause a problem in production or in the feature?

Comment: This is because Java ensures backward compatibility. I recommend running your app to see if there are no runtime errors. I believe I answered your question, so please accept the answer. Thank you.